# Bug in migration iOS5 to iOS6 "This store was previously associated with a different iCloud account"

Tags: token, icloud, account

I have a bug in my apps when I migrate to iOS5 to iOS6 : "This store was previously associated with a different iCloud account".

I have difference betweem my the current identity token: XXXXXX and This store was previously associated with a different iCloud account:XXXXXX.

Is it easy to have the current token

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
```

but I don't find a solution to recovered my previous account token.

Any ideas?

Comment: I just got this error during development.  For me it wasn't a migration issue, the store matched and didn't need migration.  I don't know what caused it, but deleting the app and it's data fixed the problem and allowed me to continue development (iCloud resynced and I didn't loose any data).  I'm hoping it's some kind of development only corruption.